# python3 no longer works on Azure functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have had my function running for a while but suddenly nothing works any more. I followed the instructions found here https://prmadi.com/running-python-code-on-azure-functions-app/ with success. The code was automatically deployed from Github. However, a few weeks ago things went wrong. I have not solved my problem but I have figured some things out:

1) the modules (using pip) I installed are gone or can no longer be found. I managed to install them but they disappear within some hours.

2) the function runs 2.7. I guess that is because the PATH has been changed. Previously \home\site\tools was in the path. That is no longer the case. What worked previously was to install python 3 using nuget site-extension and then move it to the \home\site\tools folder. I have tried to move the python3 installation to e.g. /home/site/deployments/tools which is in the path.

Update: I tried to use the instructions here: https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/python-3-6-deployments-on-azure-function-apps/. I managed to get my function running python 3 and I managed to have Azure install the required modules. So in short I have the following following folder structure:

```
requirements.txt
├── function
    ├── deploy.cmd
    ├── .deployment
    ├── function.json
    ├── run.py
```

deployment is

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: --------------------------------------------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script for Python 3.6 on Azure Functions
:: Version: 0.1
:: --------------------------------------------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling python deployment.

:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

IF NOT EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\requirements.txt" goto postPython
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\.skipPythonDeployment" goto postPython

echo Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file.


pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"

:: 2. Create virtual environment
IF NOT EXIST "D:\home\site\tools\python36*" (

  echo Creating Python 3.6.1 x64 virtual environment...
  nuget.exe install -Source https://www.siteextensions.net/api/v2/ -OutputDirectory D:\home\site\tools python361x64
  mv /d/home/site/tools/python3*/content/python*/* /d/home/site/tools/
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

) ELSE (
  echo Found compatible virtual environment.
)

:: 3. Install packages
echo Pip install requirements...
D:\home\site\tools\python.exe -m pip install -r "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\requirements.txt"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

popd

:postPython

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

This actually worked, but after a while I was either 1) back to python 2.7 and no packages or I get the error message

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.toc
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.toc ---> System.ApplicationException
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.ScriptFunctionInvoker.ExecuteScriptAsync(String path,String arguments,Object[] invocationParameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\Script\ScriptFunctionInvoker.cs : 114
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.ScriptFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\Script\ScriptFunctionInvoker.cs : 55
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Description\FunctionInvokerBase.cs : 95
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
   End of inner…
```

Despite that I can open a console and run the code without errors. So I tried to redeploy the function but with no luck. I guess that azure runs some cleanup or something at some intervals?

Best

Comment: Hi, would you please post more details about your code to let me help you ?

Comment: Hi Jay Gong. I tried to add some more details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was caused by a bug in Azure https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1758

Essentially just roll back to an old version (e.g. 1.0.11296) in "function app settings" and everything works again :-)